# Split section of array

Tags: python

If I have an array

```
{'clid': '13', 'cldbid': '4', 'cluid': 'HJhdsahdKJHDAS76823JHASDjh=', 'token': 'jadhJKHdasjhAHD182397PQe+2371ewioueqwWUE', 'tokencustomset': 'ident= value=1340', 'token1': '11', 'token2': '0'}
```

How can I split it so I get just the number `1340` from the `value=` part in the `tokencustomset`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
x = int(d['tokencustomset'].split('=')[-1])
```

would work for that exact entry.  If it works for all of your desired use cases is something you'll have to experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split this two parts
First part will take the value from key `tokencustomset` as
x = dict["tokencustomset"]

It will return output as `'ident= value=1340'`

Next part is to get the value part

There are number of techniques you can use. Either you can `split` by `=` and take the last index as mentioned in other answers

or use regex as `value=(\d+)` which will give `1340`